# How to install curl on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, curl

System:  ibook G4 / linux ubuntu 2.6.28-6-powerpc
    OS : ubuntu 9.04(jaunty)
PHP ver : 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.6

Please let me know how to install `curl` on my system. Synaptic Package Manager tells me to install `curl_7.18.2-18-ubuntu4.1_powerpc.deb` on it.

But I get this error

> No such a file on http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/c/curl

I have downloaded a later version of this file, but package manager ignores the file on disk.

Comment: sudo aptitude install libcurl3

Comment: Read **[this](http://www.linuxguide.co.cc/how-to-install-php-curl-and-upgrade-ubuntu-server/)** article, this may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install <packagename>
```

If you already have the deb file, just run:

```
sudo dpkg -i <name>.deb
```

These commands are all to be executed on the command line terminal.

Comment: no work!!!!!! w:failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports

Comment: -i //  option "i" is answer .  thank you very ~~~ much!